# How to open the Slack application installed on my cell phone with a button in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, slack-api

I need to open my Slack application installed on my cell phone through a button created in Xamarin Forms.
What I have is an interface created in the shared project and the clicked event of the button in "MainPage".
Later I have created a class in the project.android which makes a dependency injection to create an implementation to open a specific application by means of "Intent"

```
/////Interface
namespace PracticaXamarin
{
   public interface IOpenAppService
   {
     Task<bool> Launch(string stringUri);
   }
}


/////Event click of the button on MainPage
namespace PracticaXamarin
{
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
       void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
       {
           DependencyService.Get<IOpenAppService>().Launch("slack");
           //DependencyService.Get<IOpenAppService> ().Launch("com.whatsapp");
       }

       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

       }
   }
}

/////The class created in the project.android
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(OpenAppService))]
namespace PracticaXamarin.Droid
{
   public class OpenAppService : Activity, IOpenAppService
   {
       public Task<bool> Launch(string stringUri)
       {
           try
           { 
               Intent intent = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(stringUri);


               if (intent != null)
               {
                   intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                   Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
               }
               else
               {
                   intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                   intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=" + stringUri)); // This launches the PlayStore and search for the app if it's not installed on your device
                   Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
               }
               return Task.FromResult(true);
           }
           catch{
               return Task.FromResult(false);
           }

       }
   }
}
```

What I can do is pass the "Intent" of some applications such as the "Intent" of WhatSapp as shown in the commented line, which opens the WhatSapp application

```
//DependencyService.Get<IOpenAppService>().Launch("com.whatsapp");
```

But I can not find a way to open Slack's application.
Is there any I "Intent" from Slack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Slack's custom uri](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking) scheme

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("slack://open"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much this answer served me

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Slack "deep linking" via the [Xamarin.Essentials NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/) and skip the dependency service:

```cs
await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync("slack://open");
```

#### Example usage:

```cs
if (await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.CanOpenAsync("slack://"))
{
    await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync("slack://open");
}
else
{
    // Load the Store page for the Stack App... or you could just open the device's browser to https://slack.com....
    if (Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Platform == Xamarin.Essentials.DevicePlatform.iOS)
        await Xamarin.Essentials.Browser.OpenAsync("https://itunes.apple.com/app/slack-app/id618783545?ls=1&mt=8");
    else if (Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Platform == Xamarin.Essentials.DevicePlatform.Android)
        await Xamarin.Essentials.Browser.OpenAsync("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Slack&hl=en_US");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Something else..? Launch the device browser? ....");
}
```

re: https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking (skip down to "Deep linking with slack://" section)